# Multiple key identifiers for API-Platform resources

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have a Chart object which contains a collection of Serie objects and these Serie objects contain collections of Data objects.  Instead of requiring a REST API to identify the Serie and Data objects by surrogate primary keys, I wish to do so based on their position within their respective collection.

The database schema is as follows.  Originally I considered making serie's `chart_id/position` and data's `chart_id/serie_id/position` composite primary keys, however, Doctrine can only do so for [one level](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6355#issuecomment-289158628) (i.e. Serie) and to be consistent am using a surrogate keys for all tables.

```
chart
- id (PK autoincrement)
- name

serie
- id (PK autoincrement)
- position (int with unique constraint with chart_id)
- name
- chart_id (FK)

data
- id (PK autoincrement)
- position (int with unique constraint with serie_id)
- name
- serie_id (FK)
- value
```

A fully hydrated response for `/charts/1` will return the JSON shown below.  For instance, to locate the data object whose name is *Series1Data1*, the url would be `/charts/1/series/0/datas/1`, or if necessary `/datas/chart=1;seriePosition=0;dataPosition=1` would also work.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "chart1"
    "series": [{
            "chart": "/chart/1",
            "position": 0,
            "name": "series0.chart1",
            "datas": [{
                    "serie": "/charts/1/series/0",
                    "position": 0,
                    "name": "datas0.series0.chart1"
                }, {
                    "serie": "/series/chart=1;position=0",
                    "position": 1,
                    "name": "datas1.series0.chart1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "chart": "/chart/1",
            "position": 1,
            "name": "series1.chart1",
            "datas": []
        }
    ]
}
```

To change the identifiers, I used `@ApiProperty` to set `identifier` for Serie's and Data's primary key `$id` to false and for Serie's `$chart` and `$position` and Data's `$serie` and `$position` to true.

Entity/Chart.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
//use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
//use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
//use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
//use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class Chart
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Serie::class, mappedBy="chart")
     */
    private $series;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $name;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->series = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSeries(): Collection
    {
        return $this->series;
    }

    public function addSeries(Serie $series): self
    {
        exit(sprintf('Chart::addSeries() $this->series->contains($series): %s', $this->series->contains($series)?'true':'false'));
        if (!$this->series->contains($series)) {
            $this->series[] = $series;
            $series->setChart($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSeries(Serie $series): self
    {
        if ($this->series->removeElement($series)) {
            if ($series->getChart() === $this) {
                $series->setChart(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

     public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Entity/Serie.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
//use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
//use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
//use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_position_serie", columns={"chart_id", "position"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_name_serie", columns={"chart_id", "name"})})
 * @ApiResource(
 *   collectionOperations={
 *     "get1" = {  
 *       "method" = "get",
 *     },
 *     "get2" = {  
 *       "method" = "get",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "id",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Chart ID",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *         }
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "post1" = {  
 *       "method" = "post",
 *     },
 *     "post2" = {  
 *       "method" = "post",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "id",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Chart ID",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *         }
 *       }
 *     }
 *   },
 *   itemOperations={
 *     "get1" = {  
 *       "method" = "get",
 *     },
 *     "get2" = {  
 *       "method" = "get",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{position}",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *         }
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "put1" = {  
 *       "method" = "put",
 *     },
 *     "put2" = {  
 *       "method" = "put",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{position}",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *         }
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "patch1" = {  
 *       "method" = "patch",
 *     },
 *     "patch2" = {  
 *       "method" = "patch",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{position}",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *         }
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "delete1" = {  
 *       "method" = "delete",
 *     },
 *     "delete2" = {  
 *       "method" = "delete",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{position}",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *         }
 *       }
 *     }
 *   }
 * )
 */

class Serie
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Chart::class, inversedBy="series")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
    * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
    * ApiProperty(push=true)
    */
    private $chart;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
    * ApiProperty(push=true)
    */
    private $position;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Data::class, mappedBy="serie")
    */
    private $data;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
    */
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getChart(): ?Chart
    {
        return $this->chart;
    }

    public function setChart(?Chart $chart): self
    {
        $this->chart = $chart;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getData(): Collection
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function addData(Data $data): self
    {
        if (!$this->data->contains($data)) {
            $this->data[] = $data;
            $data->setSerie($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeData(Data $data): self
    {
        if ($this->data->removeElement($data)) {
            if ($data->getSerie() === $this) {
                $data->setSerie(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function setPosition(int $position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Entity/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
//use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
//use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
//use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_name_data", columns={"serie_id", "name"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_position_data", columns={"serie_id", "position"})})
 * @ApiResource(
 *   collectionOperations={
 *     "get1" = {  
 *       "method" = "get",
 *     },
 *     "get2" = {  
 *       "method" = "get",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{position}/datas",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "id",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Chart ID",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           },
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *         }
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "post1" = {  
 *       "method" = "post",
 *     },
 *     "post2" = {  
 *       "method" = "post",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{position}/datas",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "id",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Chart ID",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           },
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *         }
 *       }
 *     }
 *   },
 *   itemOperations={
 *     "get1" = {  
 *       "method" = "get",
 *     },
 *     "get2" = {  
 *       "method" = "get",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{series_position}/datas/{position}",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "series_position" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "series_position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           },
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Datas position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *           }
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "put1" = {  
 *       "method" = "put",
 *     },
 *     "put2" = {  
 *       "method" = "put",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{series_position}/datas/{position}",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "series_position" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "series_position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           },
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Datas position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *           }
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "patch1" = {  
 *       "method" = "patch",
 *     },
 *     "patch2" = {  
 *       "method" = "patch",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{series_position}/datas/{position}",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "series_position" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "series_position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           },
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Datas position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *           }
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "delete1" = {  
 *       "method" = "delete",
 *     },
 *     "delete2" = {  
 *       "method" = "delete",
 *       "path" = "/charts/{id}/series/{series_position}/datas/{position}",
 *       "requirements" = {
 *         "id" = "\d+",
 *         "series_position" = "\d+",
 *         "position" = "\d+",
 *       },
 *       "openapi_context" = {
 *         "parameters" = {
 *           {
 *             "name" = "series_position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Series position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           },
 *           {
 *             "name" = "position",
 *             "in" = "path",
 *             "required" = true,
 *             "description" = "Datas position in chart",
 *             "schema" = {
 *               "type" = "integer"
 *             }
 *           }
 *           }
 *       }
 *     }
 *   }
 * )
 */
class Data
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Serie::class, inversedBy="data")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     * ApiProperty(push=true)
     */
    private $serie;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     * ApiProperty(push=true)
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSerie(): ?Serie
    {
        return $this->serie;
    }

    public function setSerie(?Serie $serie): self
    {
        $this->serie = $serie;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setPosition(int $position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

API-Platform is able to generate an IRI for the Chart and Serie item, but not for the Data item.  I suspect this occurs because Data's `$serie` identifier property requires both the chartId and its position, but don't know how to resolve it.

I looked into [subresources](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/), however, they only support GET requests and [subresources will be deprecated in favor of multiple ApiResources](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/3689#issuecomment-714762794) (however, I don't even know what "multiple ApiResources" means).  Also, maybe related to decorating the IriConverter, but not sure.

What do I need to do to allow the Data resource to be identified by its position in the serie collection, and for the Swagger documentation to reflect doing so?

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL CONTENT**

I changed the entities in an attempt to implement two different approaches, but unfortunately neither fully work.  Should I focus my energies solely on one of the two approaches?

1. Where the identifier of the parent is in the query (i.e. `/datas/chart=1;serie_position=0;data_position=0`)
2. Where the identifier of the parent is in the path(i.e. `/charts/1/series/0/datas/0`)

If I wanted to use placeholder `chart_id` instead of `id` (i.e. `/charts/{chart_id}/series/{series_position}/datas/{position}` instead of `/charts/{id}/series/{series_position}/datas/{position}`, how can I remove or rename chart's `id`?

Should I be doing this differently so I don't need all the annotations and maybe rename chart's `id`?  To some degree I was able to get Swagger to provide the fields, but don't think I am doing it right.  Maybe by [decorating api_platform.openapi.factory](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#overriding-the-openapi-specification)?

[image]

Comment: ([Referenced at meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364337).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Api Platform can deal with such situations in different ways.

One would be to create your own **state provider** as explained in [v3
documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-providers/)

In your Data class use:

```php
#[ApiResource(
   operations: [
      new Get(
         uriTemplate: 'charts/{id}/series/{series_id}/data/{position}'),
         provider: YourCustomeStateProvider::class
      ...
   ]
)]
```

If you want to rename the id placeholder by chart_id you can :

- rename your $id variable by $chartId and put the `#[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]` attribute on it
- or use the `#[SerializedName("chart_id")]` attribute $id

Then in your state provider, you retrieve your variables through `$uriVariables['chart_id']`, `$uriVariables['series_id']` and `$uriVariables['position']` and use them with Doctrine (repo / querybuilder /etc.) to retrieve the desired data.

Note: pagination and filters will need some customization too (ie. see [pagination for custom state provider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/#pagination-for-custom-state-providers))

For write endpoints, you'll have to create your own [state processor](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-processors/).

You could also use [subresources](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/) as described in v3. But keep in mind that it won't just work by magic: updating subresources is a very subjective topic and Api Platform default provider/processor won't always cover your need in this case. That's why the documentation advise for custom provider/processor.

Comment: Thanks MendelYev.  Yes, v3 is nice!  Also, don't believe a state processor is even necessary, and a state processor is only necessary on the POST method.  Just provide the new object containing the referenced objects (added bonus, you could use the constructor and get rid of the setters).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I've found that api-platform is too-naive and very limiting for designing/implementation of good multilevel api (and api resources that generally do not conform the entities stored in ORM) and leads to unreadable/unmaintainable code really fast.

For similar use case I've resorted to a single api endpoint with three required parameters (not to mention that api-platform got removed from the project month and a half later).

Comment: Thanks kaznovac,  I believe api-platform does a good job for typical uses but also have had challenges with some edge cases.  I am pretty sure it is possible to do what I wish with it, but expect I will do differently than my current attempt.  Unfortunately, I could not find comprehensive documentation how but only piecemealed tips which often conflict with one another.

Comment: I disagree on this point. Subresources have deen debated in their github repo and no consensus was found on how to deal with write operations. Too many ways to deal with such situation. Therefore api platform provides a "naive" default persister and offers a simple way to create custom logic through state processor. Documentation might be the real issue, but it has improved a lot !

Comment: @MendelYev That was my experience with api platform v2. I can't guarantee my view is still applicable and whether the api platform team has made substantial improvements to the documentation and to the approach to api implementation - as haven't used the library since. It's always good to hear that things improve.